# postgresql difficult(for me) query

Tags: postgresql, associations

Here are the tables I have:

1. AB tuple table
2. C table which has entries with A.id and B.id
3. D table which has entries with C.id and a boolean field "open"

I want to count all the entries in D table where "open" = true and which have a C.id that has the same A.id and B.id

I want the query to return the count, the common A.id and the common B.id in a single line

For example 
D table

```
D.id = 1, open=true, D.CID = 2
D.id = 2, open=true, D.CID = 3
D.id = 3, open=true, D.CID = 3
D.id = 4, open=true, D.CID = 4
```

C table

```
C.id = 2, A.id = 3, B.id = 5 
C.id = 3, A.id = 3, B.id = 5
C.id = 4, A.id = 4, B.id = 6
```

Bc the first 3 entries in D have CID's with the same AID and BID they are counted in the same entry. Therefore, the query should return the following 2 entries:

```
1. count = 3  A.id = 3  B.id = 5
2. count = 1  A.id = 4  B.id = 6
```

I made a tuple table for AB because i thought about it working like the following psuedo code

```
For each entry i in tuple Table AB 
   for each entry j in Table C 
      for each entry k in Table D 
          if j.AID AND j.BID equal to i.AID and i.BID
              And if k.CID = j.id
                 Then returnHash[i] = returnHash[i] + 1
```

-might not be necessary though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  c.aid,
  c.bid
FROM
  d INNER JOIN c
ON
  d.cid = c.id
WHERE
  d.open
GROUP BY
  c.aid,
  c.bid;
```

Comment: I have a extended question, i would like the same thing but now with another column in the results that is the difference between the count value returned and a value existing in a field in c. I will post this as another question as well

Comment: also how can i get other fields from A table and B table that are relavant to these rows. I want to get the field A.name and B.status and add it to the rest of the columns in the row

Comment: You can add whatever columns you want in the SELECT list as well as in the GROUP BY list.